# Webpack dev server with api history fallback doesn't work with react router v6 parameterised routes

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

Using Webpack dev server locally like so:

```json
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
```

I have a router setup using react router v6 as following:

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path='/'
    element={
      <AppLayout>
        <Outlet />
      </AppLayout>
    }
  >
    <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
    <Route path='/user' element={<UserList />} />
    <Route path='/user/:id' element={<UserDetails />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Now when I refresh on `/user`, I correctly see the User Route being loaded

If I click on a link to `/user/1` the route is loaded correctly

However when I refresh on `/user/1`, I see no loaded route

Does anybody know what the issue here is? I haven't encountered this problem on previous versions of react router

Comment: Is this an issue when your app is deployed out to a server, or is it not working locally as a development build?

Comment: What do you mean by "no loaded route"? Describe what happens when you refresh the page

Comment: Issue occurs locally

You see a blank white page. The page tries to load the js file under: `localhost:8080/user/app.js`, and returns a 404

Comment: Give the [Deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment) docs a good read through to see what is relevant for how you are serving up your app locally.

Comment: Have you figured out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is older, but for anyone else that lands here and has the same problem, this is how I solved it.

in my webpack.config i updated the `devServer.historyApiFallback` key:

```js
historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [{ from: /./, to: '/index.html' }],
      index: 'index.html',
    },
```

and inside of my index.html in the `<head>` tag I added: `<base href="/" />` this allowed deep routing to work with react router. Navigating to `/child/another-child/last-child` and refreshing would NOT cause the 404 error when it tried to load the html at that nested path. Its rewriting all paths to point to `/index.html` since I'm using a SPA this makes sense. Then the code can handle rendering the correct JSX based on the path.